# How to export an entity as a CSV in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, export-to-csv

I am using the following code to output a CSV but I am getting a blank screen when I run it. basically my confusion is with the DoctrineORMQuerySourceIterator as I am not understanding how to use that properly. I am assuming I have to list out the property names ????

I am using the Sonata Exporter:

https://github.com/sonata-project/exporter

```
<?php

$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MainReferralCaptureBundle:Referral');
$referrals = $repository->createQueryBuilder('r')->select('r.pLastName, r.pFirstName')->getQuery();

// $referrals2 = $referrals->getResult();
// var_dump($referrals2);

$data = array(
    0 => array('name' => 'Jack'),
    1 => array('name' => 'Jill')
);

// Pick a format to export to
$format = 'csv';

// Filename
$filename = 'referral.csv';

// Set Content-Type
$content_type = 'text/csv';

// Location to Export this to
$export_to = 'php://output';

// Data to export
$exporter_source = new \Exporter\Source\DoctrineORMQuerySourceIterator($referrals, array('pLastName, pFirstName'));

// Get an Instance of the Writer
$exporter_writer = '\Exporter\Writer\\' . ucfirst($format) . 'Writer';

$exporter_writer = new $exporter_writer($export_to);

// Set the right headers
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-type: ' . $content_type);
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $filename . ';');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Pragma: public');

// Export to the format
\Exporter\Handler::create($exporter_source, $exporter_writer)->export();
```

Answer (score 3):

The secound parameter of the `DoctrineORMQuerySourceIterator` is an array of property names like this:

```
['Column name in the output' => 'fieldName', 'Something' => 'address.street']
```

As you can see in the [source code](https://github.com/sonata-project/exporter/blob/458980410a11689b591a67dd083188d002a43b4c/lib/Exporter/Source/DoctrineORMQuerySourceIterator.php#L57) it actually uses the [Property Accessor](http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/components/property_access/introduction.html) component to access the data (you can find more examples there).

If you want to export raw data form the db, I rocommend to use the [`PDOStatementSourceIterator`](https://github.com/sonata-project/exporter/blob/458980410a11689b591a67dd083188d002a43b4c/lib/Exporter/Source/PDOStatementSourceIterator.php) or the [`DoctrineDBALConnectionSourceIterator`](https://github.com/sonata-project/exporter/blob/458980410a11689b591a67dd083188d002a43b4c/lib/Exporter/Source/DoctrineDBALConnectionSourceIterator.php) instead as those are faster. The former requires a `PDOStatement` and the other requires a connection, a query and an array of prameters (you can see it in the linked source code) as constructor parameters.

Comment: did as you told me and I get " Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException: "Warning: spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be obj"

Answer (score 1):

A working example using the CsvWriter :

```
$format = 'csv';
$exportTo = 'php://output';
$exporterWriter = '\Exporter\Writer\\' . ucfirst($format) . 'Writer';

$data = $repository->createQueryBuilder('r')->getQuery();
$fields = array('Last Name' => 'pLastName', 'First Name' => 'pFirstName');
$source = new DoctrineORMQuerySourceIterator($data, $fields);
$writer = new $exporterWriter($exportTo);

Handler::create($source, $writer)->export();
```

Sorry for the delay before answer your issue.