# PHP Symfony 4 Export CSV

Tags: php, symfony, export, export-to-csv, symfony4

I tried to create a CSV export feature for my website. I got error: "argument passed to _construct() must be an instance of PDOStatement".
 Below is the code (php symfony 4) - please advise. Thank you!

```
<?php

use Exporter\Handler;
use Exporter\Source\PDOStatementSourceIterator;
use Exporter\Writer\CsvWriter;

// Prepare the data source
$em=$this-getDoctrine()->getManager();
$sql="select id, name from table";
$stm= $em->getConnection()->prepare($sql);
$stm->execute();

$source = new PDOStatementSourceIterator($stm);

// Prepare the writer
$writer = new CsvWriter('data.csv');

// Export the data
Handler::create($source, $writer)->export();

?>
```

Comment: $em->getConnection actually returns a Doctrine Database Abstraction Layer connection.  Not a pdo connection.  Likewise, prepare returns a DBAL statement.  Hence the mismatch.  You need to go one step lower to get the pdo connection.  $stm = $em->getConnection()->getWrappedConnection()->prepare($sql);  You will probably run into other issues but this should get you past the first step.

Comment: This answer may be what you are looking for, using the DoctrineORMQuerySourceIterator: [How to export an entity as a CSV in Symfony?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33844428/6764710)

Comment: Thank you Cerad and Yosh so much for your quick responses.  I tried Cerad's suggestion by adding getWrappedConnection() and the issue was resolved. I run into other issue "fopen(data.csv) failed to open stream: Permission denied"  .

Comment: Best to stick with one issue per question.  But before making a new question go ahead and google the error message.  Lots of possible reasons for fopen to fail.